# Cakephp 2 multidimensional cookie array not working

Tags: cakephp, cookies, multidimensional-array

I'm unable to read the cookie created use cakephp cookie component. 
Actually cookies are creating and when i debug right after write method it displaying the entire cookies. But if i refresh the same page (action) cookies are not reading. On other controller action also cookies are not reading.

```
var $components = array('Encryption','General','Cookie');

public function beforeFilter()
{
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow();   

    $this->Cookie->name =null;
    $this->Cookie->time =2592000;  // or '30 days'
    $this->Cookie->path = '/';
    $this->Cookie->domain =  $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    //$this->Cookie->secure = true;  // i.e. only sent if using secure HTTPS
    $this->Cookie->key = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
    //$this->Cookie->httpOnly = true;
    $this->Cookie->type('aes');
}
public function index(){    
    $browserInfo=$this->General->getBrowser();
    $browserName=$browserInfo['name'];
    $cookie_value=md5(uniqid(rand(), true))."_".$browserName;

    $knowTheBae= $this->Cookie->read('know_the_bae'); // this is returning null when i' refresh the page again. 

    if(count($knowTheBae)==0){  
        $this->Cookie->write('know_the_bae.identity',$cookie_value); //this line suppose to execute only first time. But it's executing every time i load this page .
        debug($this->Cookie->read('know_the_bae')); //line no 43
    }
    if($this->Cookie->read('know_the_bae.identity')!=""){
        if($this->Session->read('Auth.User.id')){
            $this->Cookie->write('know_the_bae.user.name',$this->Session->read('Auth.User.username'));
            $this->Cookie->write('know_the_bae.user.id',$this->Session->read('Auth.User.id'));
        }else{
            $this->Cookie->write('know_the_bae.user.name','UNKN_USR');
            $this->Cookie->write('know_the_bae.user', array('name' => 'UNKN_USR', 'role' => 'guest'));

        }
    }else{
        $this->Cookie->write('know_the_bae.identity',$cookie_value);
    }
    $this->Cookie->write("know_the_bae.test",'something going wrong');

    debug($this->Cookie->read('know_the_bae')); //line no 59
}
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMtZF.png) [browser cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5IeF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a random key to encrypt and decrypt your cookies:

```
$this->Cookie->key = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
```

This will be different on the next page load, so it will fail to decrypt what you had set. You must always use the same key, I'd suggest you store it in a secure configuration file or environment variable.

Comment: Found out the same after few debugging. Thanks @Greg for the very prompt reply. Changed the code like this $this->Cookie->key = Configure::read('cookie_enc_key');